# Why does string.split() behave differently for Regular Expressions?

Tags: javascript, regex, split

In JavaScript, if I run the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var nameStr = 'Chris Kate Steve';
var names = nameStr.split(/[ ]/);
var names2 = nameStr.split(' ');

for (var i in names)
{
    alert(i);
}

for (var i in names2)
{
    alert(i);
}
</script>
```

It will alert:

> 0
>
> 1
>
> 2
>
> index
>
> input

For the first set and:

> 0
>
> 1
>
> 2

For the second set.

Any idea why this is?

Comment: It worked correctly for me. I tried it in IE8, FF 3.6.3 and Opera 10.53.

Comment: If you run .exec() on a RegExp, it will return an array that includes:

index (the zero-based index of the match in the string)
input (the original string, str)

But why would Chrome return those in a split statement?

Comment: I was not able to reproduce this in IE 8 or Firefox 3.  I got "0", "1", and "2" for both.  Are you using a different browser maybe?

Comment: It alerts 0,1,2 and 0,1,2 on Chrome.

Comment: Rename "names" to "names3" and see if it comes up with the same result.

Comment: @John: I checked the exact code on Chrome 6, both returned Arrays with only [0],[1],[2], and ["length"].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`split` method with a string as input returns an array of substrings. So the returned `Array` object just has its elements as its contents.

`split` method with a regex as  input returns an `Array` object that has substrings at its numerical index positions and the input string and the index of first match stored at their respective properties (just like the return value of `string.match()` / `regex.exec()` function) - hence the `input` and `index` properties.

Answer (score 4):

`for...in` iterates over properties of an object – using it with arrays is unreliable, and should be avoided. Use `for(var i=0; i < names.length; i++)` and your problem will be solved.

It's just that split returns additional properties to the result with regexp.